# Avalon mining issue

Tags: miner-configuration, bfgminer, avalon

Pretty much a newbie to mining and got an Avalon (Nano 3) to start, I'm running Windows 8.1 and using the LPC USB VCom port (COM3).

AvalonGUI runs about 5 minutes at 3-4 GH/s - then closes/stops operating.  No info in the Avalon.log. But according to slush pool, my worker does work. I stopped using AvalonGUI and have tried to get BFGminer (4.7.0) running.  the hash rate stays at 0 even though it sees the device.

Here is my BFGminer command line:

"bfgminer -0 stratum+tcp://us-east.stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -S avalon:\.\COM3 -u xxxxxxx -P ppppppp"

I am getting 'Avalon: Reset Failed! not an Avalon?' error.

Any help would be appreciated! time costs money :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely you have done something wrong, Are you sure you are using the correct program (Nano GUI?)

Here is an image for the .ini and what it should like:
http://postimg.org/image/qak22zij9/2c2b57c6/

Finally, don't expect much from this miner. it's merely a way to start mining but the profit from mining might barely cover it's cost.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I guess that's been the issue all along. I removed all the software (USB driver and Avalon service/UI) and downloaded the 'Avalon Nano Quickstart'. Installed the USB driver from the download, modify the Avalon.ini- edited the COM port . Launched gui, closed gui, plugged in Nano and launched GUI again. I've been running now for ~8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I use an avalon nano and to work properly I found this command line.

1. Be sure to install avalon software
   http://downloads.canaan-creative.com/software/avalon_nano/software/latest/AvalonInstaller.zip
2. Copy bfgminer folder from "c:\Program files\Avalon" or "c:\Program files (x86)\Avalon" to the folder of your choice (c:\bfgminer)
3. Uninstall avalon.
4. Open notepad and create  a file bfgminer-avalon.bat and put this in it (substituting your own credentials):

> BfgMiner.exe  -o stratum+tcp://eu.multipool.us:3363 -O workersname:workerspassword  -T  -S ICA:\.\COM4   --set-device  ICA:baud=115200  --set-device  ICA:reopen=timeout  --set-device  ICA:work_division=1  --set-device  ICA:fpga_count=1  --set-device  ICA:probe_timeout=100  --set-device  ICA:timing=0.22